# How to use selenium to start a specified chrome browser

Tags: macos, selenium, chrome-web-driver, virtual-environment

First, I have a chrome browser v75(this is the one I use every day). And I download an old version(v61.0) with which I want to deploy selenium crawler.
But the question is each time when I try to run this crawler. It always executes the v75 version rather than v61.0
I have downloaded their corresponding chromedriver and configured them already.
My first trial is to specify the headers which tell the browser version.But it doesn't work. 
So should I write some script to add them to the system path?
PS:I want to run this in a virtual environment and I'm using Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the below chrome option as part of options.

**Here is the solution in Python:**

```
# replace the path with the location where you have older version of chrome.exe
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.binary_location= "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
# load the options 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```